# why PDOException didnt show an error in my browser?

Tags: pdo

```
<?php

class MyConnection {

    protected $username = 'root';
    protected $password = '';
    protected $host = 'localhost';
    protected $db_name = 'testdbewewewewe';

    public function connection() {
        try {

            $this->dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=". $this->host . ";dbname=".     $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);


        } catch (PDOException $e) {$e->getMessage();}
    }


}



?>
```

hi im new in PDO i hope someone can asnwer my curiousity on this one, i try to make a connection in mysql using php with PDO, but when i already make this code the browser doesn't show any error all is doing good, but when i tried to intentionally make the database name wrong the browser didn't show any error at all and i'm just curious if im i really doing it right?

Comment: Learn about error reporting in php. If its turned off in server settings (php.ini) then you won't see any error but a blank page when you get a critical error. But following the buddy's answer below, you can get warning and exceptions putting the code in your php file, But not critical error or syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

Just because your error reporting is wrong.

[You should not catch error exceptions to show them in the browser](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors) - PHP can already do it for you.

So, make your class this way

```
class MyConnection {

    protected $username = 'root';
    protected $password = '';
    protected $host = 'localhost';
    protected $db_name = 'testdbewewewewe';

    public function connection() {
            $this->dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=". $this->host . ";dbname=".     $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
    }
}
```

Then tell PHP to show errors in the browser,

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$conn = new MyConnection();
$conn->connection();
```

And have your exception shown first class.